# salesforce api supports all sales cloud editions?

Tags: api, salesforce

salesforce api supports all sales cloud editions(Contact Manager, Group, Professional, Enterprise, Unlimited)? If it supports, please give the reference URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the API, your organization must be on one of the following 3 editions.  Note that this feature is enabled by default:

1. Enterprise Edition
2. Unlimited Edition
3. Developer Edition

The API package is not available for the following editions:

1. Personal Edition
2. Group Edition
3. Professional Edition*

   *Certified partner applications, such as the PE version of the Excel Connector, are granted an API token once they have completed a security review. This API token is sometimes referred to as a "Client ID". API requests identified with a certified partner application's API token are allowed to operate with Professional Edition orgs. More information on Partner Certification can be found here:http://wiki.apexdevnet.com/index.php/Certification_FAQ.

Detailed [limits](https://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/integrate_api_rate_limiting.htm)

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406611/direct-login-and-federated-login-in-salesforce

Comment: You can also purchase API access for a professional edition org as an additional extra.